# Self-designed objective for linear regression learning

Tags: regression, linear-regression

A multiple linear regression is to use several predictor variables to predict the outcome of a response variable, like the following relationship:

$y_{i}=\beta_{1}x_{i1}+...+\beta_{p}x_{ip}+\epsilon_{i},   i=1,...,n$

I understand the typical objective to learn the $\beta$ paramters is least-squares, which means to minimize the sum of the sqaure of $\epsilon_{i}$. Now I want other kinds of objective, for example **to maximize the Shannon entropy of the sequences of $\epsilon$** (or other self-specified objective). I googled towards this direction but no luck. I am wondering if there is any problem (and tool to solve it if possible) I can look into to do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: This is too vague...are you interested in the Shannon Entropy specifically?

Comment: @Bey Yes, let's say Shannon Entropy.

Comment: Ok, well unlike least squares, the Shannon Entropy requires that you be able to assign a probability or density value to each error. Do you want to assume a gaussian error with mean 0 and a pre-specified stdev? Also, do you really want to maximize entropy or minimize entropy?

Comment: @Bey You are right a pdf is needed. But since we get a sequence of error, i.e. {epsilon_i}, can we use emperical distribution? I think it is the simplist and roughest way but please tell me if I am wrong (like using a Gaussian actually help). And I want to maximize entropy.

Comment: @Bey And I am also interested in general if there is any other theory or tool to support self-desinged objective, other than least-square, for multiple linear regression. If a general method or tool is available, I believe I can apply my particular case (just make the objective Shannon entropy).

Comment: @Bey Actually, the underlying reason of why I am trying this is because I try to use a linear-regression kind of "filter" to process the sequences {x_i} and try to make the "filtered" sequence have maximum entropy (i.e. In fact I try to use x_i as y_i). If you have any other comments about how I can do this or whether this makes sense, your comments are welcome. I hope I am not confusing you.

Comment: I really don't follow what you are trying to do. Perhaps a small example? In theory, any increasing function of $\epsilon$ can be used, but not all of these generate sensible fits. The problem with entropy is that if you want to maximize it, you will be generating horrible fits.

Comment: @Bey If to maximize entropy, I think you are probably right about getting horrible fits. But my purpose is not fitting. I am sorry I confuse you but the following might be clear. I just want to get a sequence (1) having linear relationship (like a transformation) with the original one (2) having maximum entropy.

Comment: Here's the problem: the empirical distribution puts $\frac{1}{n}$ probability  on each residual, so it will always result in the minimum entropy (uniform)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems really old, it may be helpful to new visitors.

Yes, we can define any objective function and use gradient descent to minimize it. For that the objective function need to have some properties like

- It should be convex function else we'll stuck at local minima or may never find the minimum value
- It must be differentiable on every point and must have non zero derivative. Else gradient descent will not make progress and get stuck

If cost function have these properties then we can use tensorflow (or other library) to create graph to calculate the cost and then to calculate its gradient using auto-diff algorithm and use gradient descent to minimize it.

Auto-diff basically breaks calculation of cost function into elementary arithmetic computation like addition, multiplication, division etc and use chain rule to find derivative.